# How to stop browser download javascript file after redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using `iframe` in my website. There is a `<script src='/demo.js'></script>` reference inside the html in the `iframe`. In the server side, the content of the `demo.js` is as below:

```
window.location.replace('https://i3dfjejwog6.cloudfront.net/demo/index.js');
```

it just redirects the request to a different url. When I load the website, the browser will download the `index.js` from above redirect url instead of loading it as a javascript file. How can I make the browser to load the file as javascript?

I have checked this post: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) but it doesn't work because I don't have permission to update `demo.js` file so I am looking for a redirect solution.

Comment: Just put that URL in your script tag instead of demo.js?

Comment: Otherwise, check out dynamic script loading at the duplicate target.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I don't have permission to update `demo.js` file. Is there another solution?

Comment: If you redirect to a script tag, it will not execute. It needs to be loaded from a script tag

Comment: Does this mean I can't solve this issue until I am able to modify the html file ?

Comment: Or modify `https://i3dfjejwog6.cloudfront.net/demo/index.js` so that it returns HTML code and response headers.

Comment: Do you mean write html code inside the index.js?

Comment: I mean to serve an HTML response at that URL, rather than a JavaScript one.

Comment: the problem I have is that I don't have permission to update the html file.